# JAVA использовать JToggleButton в другом методе одно класса

Tags: java

Есть класс, в котором несколько методов.

```
public static class mysql implements ActionListener {

     JFrame topFrame = (JFrame)SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String ownip;
        String gettime;
        try {
            ownip = Getip.getip();
            gettime = Gettime.getip();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(topFrame, "Error getIp");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        StringBuilder lp = List.list();
        try {

            // opening database connection to MySQL server
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            // getting Statement object to execute query
            stmt = con.createStatement();

            String sql = "kakoi-to zapros";

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

             itemStateChanged();

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(topFrame, "Error SQL");
        }

    }
    public void itemStateChanged() {
        String icon = (Start.isSelected()) ? "/button_off.png" : "/button_on.png";
        Start.setIcon(new ImageIcon(gui.class.getResource(icon))); 
    }
}

private JFrame frmAnticheat;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                gui window = new gui();
                window.frmAnticheat.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public gui() {
    initialize();
}


private void initialize() {
    frmAnticheat = new JFrame();
    frmAnticheat.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    JToggleButton Start = new JToggleButton("", false);

    Start.setIcon(new ImageIcon(gui.class.getResource("/button_on.png")));
    Start.setBounds(108, 85, 132, 45);
    Start.setFocusable(false);
    Start.setBorderPainted(false);

    Start.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    frmAnticheat.getContentPane().add(Start);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
    lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(gui.class.getResource("/background4.png")));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 346, 143);
    frmAnticheat.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    Start.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

    Start.addActionListener(actionListener);
}
 }
```

Как в месте:

```
 public void itemStateChanged() {
    String icon = (Start.isSelected()) ? "/PFP/button_off.png" : 
 "/PFP/button_on.png";
    Start.setIcon(new ImageIcon(gui.class.getResource(icon)));
```

Указать, что под

> Start

я подразумеваю

> JToggleButton Start = new JToggleButton("", false);

Comment: В вопросе по ссылке та же проблема, что и у Вас, просто с другими классами/переменными. Ответ с наибольшим числом голосов показывает где объявить переменную.

Comment: спасибо, попробую